# Exploit monetarily a large unused cluster

Tags: cluster

At work we have a 200 core unused cluster, most of the researchers working here just left and nowadays almost nobody uses it. We would take advantage of it. Previously somebody asked it how to exploit it in an [academic](https://serverfault.com/questions/39627/usage-ideas-for-a-cluster-at-a-university) way. But here, and given our lack of funding, we wonder how could exploit these resources monetarily. I heard about offering video rendering services, but wonder which other services would be interesting and where to find them and how to offer them.

Comment: Keep to your core business. If you're not a service provider, I would advice not to become one now. Why not just sell the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

you can always mine bitcoins; crack hashes. question is... who paid for the cluster, who pays for the electricity, are you allowed to obtain funding by selling services provided by the cluster you have under your control?

this can quickly create a geay zone when revenue is not accounted.